# MFC CString "find" return code, microsoft site is down

Tags: mfc, cstring

The URL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314323(v=vs.60).aspx is not working for me so i cant read about it.

If anyone can help me, when trying to find a char in a CString (e.g int location = obj.find(",")) 
if it didnt find "," in the line, what does the int-location returns ? -1 ?
I cant build and test my program now to verify it returns -1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Windows CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms928981.aspx) version of the documentation suggests that -1 is indeed the return value when the search fails.

Comment: Thanks, does return '-1' when char is not found on the line string.